# Only load iframe when mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey i want want the iframe to only load when the mosue is hovering on it.

I only want it to laod when the mouse is over because i have many of them and the loading speed of the site is very bad.

Any ideas?

i already tried if with a hidden div around it but i dont like that option

```js
$(".text").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children(".test").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".test").hide();
});
```

```css
.text {
    color: #069;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.test {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size:120%;"><b><a class="text"> &#128065;
 
 <iframe class="test" src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></iframe>
</a></b></span>
            
            
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the `src` of the iframe. Only set it when the user hovers for the first time.

In the below snippet you can see the page inside of iframe is not loaded initially until you hover over the eye.

I have intentionally commented `display: none;` so that you can observe that page is not loaded.

```js
$(".text").mouseover(function() {
    var src = $(this).children(".test").attr('src');
    if(!src){
      src = $(this).children(".test").attr('data-src');
      $(this).children(".test").attr('src', src);
    }
    $(this).children(".test").show();
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).children(".test").hide();
});
```

```css
.text {
    color: #069;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.test {
    //display: none;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size:120%;"><b><a class="text"> &#128065;
 
 <iframe class="test" data-src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"></iframe>
</a></b></span>
            
            
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow thanks that was quick, one more question. i load the src with php code so the html code is echoed in php and i fill the src of the iframe with different attributes and variables. Im not able to do it it in the js file beacuse there i dont have all the variables etc. any idea on that aswell?

Comment: you can set the url in a different attribute on the iframe like `data-src` and use it in your javascript code to have the src url

Comment: @Cepturion See the modified answer.